# How to insert more than one piece of a data into a single cell of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am interested to know how to add more than one piece of data into one line of data into a cell of UITableView.

For example in the StopWatch of the Clock App in Iphone, they are able to have more than one piece of data.

```
Lap  Time     Total
1    00.01.5  00.01.5
```

Interested to know how to add three values into one cell at a time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create your own cell, which inherits from UITableViewCell.
[Here's an example](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx) of how to create your custom UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a custom uitableviewcell for that checkout this [tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Videos/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx) or refer to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You could either subclass UITableViewCell, or you could choose the "Custom" attribute on IB on the cell, and drag and drop labels, buttons, and whatever you want into the UITableViewCell. Set tags on each IBOutlet you create. Then you can do like this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UILabel *yourLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tag]; // Set your own tag and outlet.
```

From there you can customize it just how you want, without having to subclass it.

When that is said, the usual way is to subclass UITableViewCell. That way, you can have each cell store information, and add the IBOutlets as properties to the `CustomTableViewCell` as normal. Then you could add the information to the `CustomTableViewCell`, and let the cell take care of the rest.